# integration until infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_4^\infty \frac{0.697(x-4)}{x^{3.5}} \, dx$$

I first bring out the constants,

so it becomes $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}0.697\int\limits_4^t \frac{(x-4)}{x^{3.5}} \,dx$

I break up the integral to  $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}0.697\int\limits_4^t x^{-2.5} - 4x^{-3.5} \, dx$

so I evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}0.697\left[\frac{-x^{-1.5}}{-1.5}+ 4\frac{x^{-2.5}}{2.5}\right]_4^t$

and get $0 - \frac{4^{-1.5}}{-1.5}  + 4\frac{x^{-2.5}}{-2.5}$

I get the answer $0.0232379001$. Would appreciate it if somebody can verify this. Thank you. If i wrong, please explain your answer.

Comment: The Maple command $$int((.697*(x-4))/x^{3.5}, x = 4 .. infinity)  $$ outputs $0.02323333333 .$

Comment: Thank you so  much! But strictly speaking, in the original qn I posted, 2.5(0.6)^2.5 = 0.6971370023 not perfectly 0.697 so that explains why i got 0.232379001 instead of 0.023233333333333